# Ubuntu related Stack Overflow Careers ad

Tags: discussion, design, stackexchange

Why aren't there a "looking for a job" section in Askubuntu like other Stack Exchange sites ( stackoverflow , server fault .. )

I think it will be cool to show stack Overflow linux/ubuntu Careers ads.

Comment: There is not really jobs in Ubuntu, the way there is in programming. Programming is a huge area with many facets to it, Ubuntu is a tiny little community OS and I don't think you can even be qualified in "Ubuntu", just the related fields, ie networking. Just my opinion on it. If you do want to work for Canonical, look here https://www.canonical.com/careers

Comment: I mean if someone is surfing Askubuntu site , he would be interested in system engineering , devops tools , scripting development jobs .. I've seen this in server fault , I opened a question about ansible and then there was some ads about ansible and devops jobs

Comment: @zanna True but it seems I misinterpreted the question anyway :)

Comment: So you are asking why we don't have the targeted ads like the other sites, not why we don't have jobs specifically for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes,  kind of that

Comment: The only Ubuntu-specific jobs I can imagine would be working for Canonical. Everything else is just Linux-related, not Ubuntu. In any case, the SO.jobs thing includes Linuxy jobs, if that's what you're looking for. Why would they set up separate sub sites for each SE site?

Comment: @terdon I'm talking about ads, something like [this](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d6baf94e3166e1490623e573563ab5a9) not a sub site like http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds more like a feature request than a topic of discussion. I would assume the advertising is placed where the advertiser feels they will gain the most relevant exposure but I have no involvement in stack exchange ad sales on either side of the transaction.

Comment: If your looking for a help desk job, there are numerous temporary employment agencies that might have something you'd be interested in (in my area anyway, not sure where you are but it might be worth looking)